# AlAssetPropertyDate returns wrong date like 121586-08-24 02:03:49 +0000

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdate, alasset

```
ALAsset *asset = ..../ initialization
NSDate *date  = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
```

which return's a date object, but the problem is some of the date object which are return from AlAsset is wrong like `121586-08-24 02:03:49 +0000` this scenario is only for some of the dates.

Can anyone let me know what is wrong with my code??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably the date is not set, or, more likely, is set to a 64-bit value of all ones.

Comment: So how to convert it to actual date?? is there any way to get correct date??

Comment: (If you're really curious, do `[date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` and `[date timeIntervalSince1970]`, cast both to `long long`, and log them in hex format.  Likely one or the other will be all ones.)

Comment: This is what i am getting Date  121586-08-24 02:03:49 +0000
referenceDate 36ea5872b85 == sinceDate 36edfd6f405
Hex value referenceDate is 0x36ea5872b85 == sinceDate is 0x36edfd6f405

Comment: and this for Correct Date - Date -- 2014-06-05 15:18:47 +0000
referenceDate 1940c1d7 == sinceDate 53908a57
Hex value of referenceDate is 0x1940c1d7 == sinceDate is 0x53908a57

Comment: Dumb question:  Was the date set correctly on the camera?

Comment: actually those images are getting displayed properly on device, but the same images downloaded to simulator and on run the code it giving this problem, the image same on device give date 2009-02-21 05:30:04 +0000

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this ..

```
NSDate *date=[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];

NSString *datestring = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date
                                                      dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
                                                      timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

After that you get the result in string